# open a file only from the application that own created

Tags: java, android

Is there a solution to create an android application where there is a download system and the file can only be accessed in that application, for example an audio and video file. Just like Joox or Spotify, when users download music, only in each application can access the music.

Comment: in all app, they download media files and store in decrypt way, you need to implement some decryption and compression methods on media files

Comment: For the case of these 2 applications, it does use encryption for the file, but is there any other way besides using the method ?? For example, download a file and put it in a private folder. I'm very confused and haven't found a case study to download the file and put it in the private folder.

Comment: then in this case simply put in a private folder and remove or change the extension of files, but manually anyone can open it

Comment: is it not problematic when I access the file when I save it with another extension??

Comment: well in one of my project i am saving all media files with extension in private folder(using .foldername, '.' in front of folder make folder hidden) in external storage(internal storage may casue storage full), without extension, other apps like music and video apps will not detect those files.. but the best approach is use encryption and decryption .

Comment: or use new File(RetailApplication.getInstance().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
 for internal data folder, only access on rooted phones or by rooted permission access apps

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, when you store files in your App's private directory. Example in documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#WriteInternalStorage

```
val sourceFile = File("Absolute/Path/To/Source/File")
val privateFileName = "privatefile"
context.openFileOutput(privateFileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).use {
    it.write(sourceFile.readBytes())
}
val newFile = File(context.filesDir, privateFileName)
if (newFile.exists() && newFile.length > 0) {
    //You succeeded.
}
```

This will create a file in private folder (Code is in Kotlin). Only your app can access it. Inside stream you can write to it any data you want.

Comment: I'm still confused to implement it. Here I use downloadmanager to download a file. Are there examples for me to learn? Sorry before, I am very ordinary to interact with files.

Comment: What is wrong with sample provided in docs? It's four lines of code, that show how to create file and write bytes into it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the documentation, I'm just wrong because I don't understand about interacting a file on an Android studio. What I'm confused is, when I have successfully downloaded a file using downloadmanager, then what should I do when the file has been downloaded? And how to check whether or not the file was made in a private folder ??

Comment: It's another question. ) You should copy downloaded file using sample code. You can check if file exists using .exists() method on file.

Comment: Sorry if I ask another question, and I am very layman for this. Ohh, I will try later from your suggestion. thanks ...

Comment: I have more questions, to access the private folder, is an Android phone required to be rooted or without root conditions can still be accessed from the application?

Comment: You can access your app's private folder without root. Others - only with root.